# What is Id parameter on CoreService2010Client Localize method

Tags: tridion

I need to localize a bunch of content components for testing to prove the different sites I have created for each support language is pulling from the correct content.

I see Core services (`CoreService2010Client`) has a method `Localize`, but, in general, how do you use it? Specifically, I'm wonder if calling it just localizes the component and then I can modify the component? Do I still need to call `CheckOut` and `CheckIn` on the TCM Id of the language item?

```
public RepositoryLocalObjectData Localize(string id, ReadOptions readBackOptions)
```

Once I get all the components localized and acceptance testing passes, what is the easiest way to UN-Localize everything I did?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `id` parameter stands for "The identifier of the item (TCM URI or WebDav URL)". This means that you are localizing the item in the context of the Publication you specified as part of that ID.

For unlocalizing you can use method `RepositoryLocalObjectData UnLocalize(string id, ReadOptions2010 readBackOptions)` on the same client interface `ICoreService2010`.

You can find the API docs on SdlTridionWorld.com (log in) -> Downloads -> Documentation -> SDL Tridion 2011 (or SDL Tridion 2011SP1).

Localizing an item has nothing to do with CheckIn CheckOut. Localizing will simply create a 'local copy' of that item, which later on you can choose to modify, save, etc, or unLocalize.

Comment: Thanks for the path to the documents. I needed that!!